# How to run the Clojure REPL from Emacs after setting up .emacs.d folder

Tags: emacs, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, emacs24, dot-emacs

I'm new to Emacs so its all a bit new to me. I got a hang of the basics of Emacs like navigation,etc. 
I was trying to install a Clojure REPL in Emacs, i cloned a .emacs repo and replaced .emacs with it. I opened up Emacs again, i'm at a loss as to how to fire up the clojure REPL.

https://github.com/ghoseb/dotemacs

this is the .emacs repo i'm using.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Folder Name

Just to clarify, you want the repo you cloned to be called `.emacs.d`. It should contain an elisp file called `init.el`, which Emacs will run on startup.

#### Starting a REPL

For this configuration, you should be able to use `M-x nrepl-jack-in` to start a repl.

To be honest, I recommend you use one of the publicly-maintained emacs configurations rather than someone's personal settings (which they may change or break at any time). [Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) and [Emacs Live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live) have good Clojure settings.

Comment: And the .emacs.d file should be in the home directory, isnt?

Comment: Yes. But it should be a directory, not a file!